# Why does Dictionary needs need to implement IDeserializationCallback?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I have a general understanding on how ISerializable works e.g. how formatter constructs a `SerializationInfo` and pass it to the object (let's say Dictionary) and when the foramtter does deserialization, it retrieves `SerializationInfo` and calls Dictionary's specail protected constructor and pass this object etc. Below is some code(simplified by me) in regards to Dictionary:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: ...ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback  {
   
   private SerializationInfo m_siInfo; // Only used for deserialization
   
   // Special constructor to control deserialization
   protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
      // During deserialization, save the SerializationInfo for OnDeserialization
      m_siInfo = info;
   }

   // implements ISerializable for serialization purpose
   public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
      info.AddValue("Version", m_version);
      info.AddValue("Comparer", m_comparer, typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>));
      info.AddValue("HashSize", (m_ buckets == null) ? 0 : m_buckets.Length);
      if (m_buckets != null) {
         KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[Count];
         CopyTo(array, 0);
        info.AddValue("KeyValuePairs", array, typeof(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]));
      }
   }

   // implement IDeserializationCallback, so this method will be called after deserialization, which set the dictionary internal state bakc to its original state before serialization
   public virtual void OnDeserialization(Object sender) {    
      if (m_siInfo == null) return; // Never set, return
      Int32 num = m_siInfo.GetInt32("Version");
      Int32 num2 = m_siInfo.GetInt32("HashSize");
      m_comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)
      m_siInfo.GetValue("Comparer", typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>));
      ...// reconstruct the Dictionary's internal states such as buckets, entries etc

   }
   ...
}
```

I have a question: Why does Dictionaryneeds need to implement IDeserializationCallback rather than just do every thing in the specail constructor?

as canton7 said:

> The dictionary's contents are serialized when the dictionary is serialized -- every key and value stored in the dictionary is serialized. The dictionary cannot calculate the hash codes for any of its contents until they've finished being deserialized. Therefore the calculation of the hash codes is deferred until OnDeserialization, by which point each of the keys and values in the dictionary have finished being deserialized, and it is safe to call methods on them

But below is the quote from the book CLR via C#:

> When a formatter serializes an object graph, it looks at each object. If its type implements the
> ISerializable interface, then the formatter ignores all custom attributes and instead constructs
> a new System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo object. This object contains the
> actual set of values that should be serialized for the object.

We can see that it is the `SerializationInfo` object will be serialized, the Dictionary object itself won't be serilailized.

As the formatter extracts `SerializationInfo` object from the stream, it creates a new Dictionary object (by calling the `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` method). Initially, all of this Dictionary object’s fields are set to 0 or null.

And we already have `SerializationInfo` object back and passed it to the special constructor, you have all original keys/values before serialization, then you can reconstruct the Dictionary's internal states in the specail constructor just as

```
protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {    
   if (info == null) return; // Never set, return
   Int32 num = info.GetInt32("Version");
   Int32 num2 = info.GetInt32("HashSize");
   m_comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)
   info.GetValue("Comparer", typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>));
   ...// reconstruct the Dictionary's internal states such as buckets, entries etc
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting your code from, but if you look at the [actual source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Dictionary.cs,152):

> ```cs
> protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
> {
>     // We can't do anything with the keys and values until the entire graph has been deserialized
>     // and we have a resonable estimate that GetHashCode is not going to fail.  For the time being,
>     // we'll just cache this.  The graph is not valid until OnDeserialization has been called.
>     HashHelpers.SerializationInfoTable.Add(this, info);
> }
> ```

From the comment, the problem is clear: the serialized data will contain the dictionary's entries, yes, but also serialized versions of the keys for those entries. The dictionary needs to re-calculate the hash code of each entry (answered in another of your many questions on this), and it can't do this until each entry has been properly deserialized. Since the order of deserialization is not guaranteed (answered in another of your questions), the dictionary needs to wait until the entire graph has been reconstructed before calculating any of those hash codes.

---

Let's take a simple example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container() { Name = "Test" };
        container.Dict.Add(container, "Container");
        
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, container);
        
        stream.Position = 0;
        formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Container : ISerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyDictionary Dict { get; }
    
    public Container()
    {
        Dict = new MyDictionary();
    }
    
    protected Container(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Container deserialized");

        Name = info.GetString("Name");
        Dict = (MyDictionary)info.GetValue("Dict", typeof(MyDictionary));
    }
    
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("Dict", Dict);
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object other) => (other as Container)?.Name == Name;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Name.GetHashCode();
}

[Serializable]
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<object, object>
{
    public MyDictionary() { }

    protected MyDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDictionary deserialized");
        
        // Look at the data which Dictionary wrote...
        var kvps = (KeyValuePair<object, object>[])info.GetValue("KeyValuePairs", typeof(KeyValuePair<object, object>[]));
        Console.WriteLine("Name is: " + ((Container)kvps[0].Key).Name);
    }
}
```

Run it here: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SSlKyg).

(I subclassed Dictionary so we know when its deserialization constructor is called).

This prints:

```
MyDictionary deserialized
Name is:
Container deserialized
```

Notice how MyDictionary is deserialized first, before Container is deserialized, despite the fact that MyDictionary contains Container as one of its keys! You can also see that `Container.Name` is `null` when MyDictionary is deserialized -- that only gets assigned to later on, some time before `OnDeserialization` is called.

Since `Container.Name` is `null` when the MyDictionary is constructed, and `Container.GetHashCode` depends on `Container.Name`, then obviously incorrect things would happen if Dictionary tried to call `GetHashCode` on any of its items' keys at that point.

Comment: I undestand the dictionary needs to re-calculate the hash code of each entry( thanks to your answer too). But this scenario is a little bit different, it is not lilke FiledA depends on FieldB, and you can't control FieldB to be serilized FieldB first followed by FieldA. Now the situation is like I manually get FieldB first, and then get FieldA and do sth on FieldA with FieldB in hand.

Comment: continued from aoove, so why I can move all the code `Int32 num = m_siInfo.GetInt32("Version");
      Int32 num2 = m_siInfo.GetInt32("HashSize"); m_comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)
      m_siInfo.GetValue("Comparer", typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>)); ...// reconstruct the Dictionary's internal states such as buckets, entries` to the special constructor if I have complete control on which field will be available first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to describe with FieldA and FieldB. The dictionary's **contents** are serialized when the dictionary is serialized -- every key and value stored in the dictionary is serialized. The dictionary cannot calculate the hash codes for any of its contents until they've finished being deserialized. Therefore the calculation of the hash codes is deferred until `OnDeserialization`, by which point each of the keys and values in the dictionary have finished being deserialized, and it is safe to call methods on them

Comment: oh I see what's the part that confuses me. You said " The dictionary's contents are serialized when the dictionary is serialized -- every key and value stored in the dictionary is serialized."  I think it is not like this,  key and value are serialized via `SerializationInfo` object, you can see key value pair is saved in `SerializationInfo` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,293). Then it is `SerializationInfo` object who contains keys and values gets serialized not the Dictionary object.

Comment: (continued from above) So whenever you get `SerializationInfo` object back (`SerializationInfo` object is deserialized first and then passed to the special constructor) , you have all complete keys values, then you can reconstruct the Dictionary's internal states in the specail constructor.

Comment: And below is the quote from the book  "When a formatter serializes an object graph, it looks at each object. If its type implements the
ISerializable interface, then the formatter ignores all custom attributes and instead constructs"
a new System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo object. This object contains the
actual set of values that should be serialized for the object."

Comment: I have edit my post and add some stuff to explain more clear, I think the fundamental part is you think the Dictionary object gets serialized, while I think only the `SerializationInfo` object (contains Dictionary's key/value) gets serialized. Since this object has all the information the Dictionary need to recalcuate the hash code,we can retrieve the value and operate on the Dictionary object(uninitialized) directly in the special constructor

Comment: I think you're getting too hung up on the term "serialized". The Dictionary serializes itself by writing various bits of data to `SerializationInfo`. The SerializationInfo is serialized to a stream by `BinaryFormatter`. Those are both serialization steps.

Comment: yes I agree with you, as  SerializationInfo is serialized to a stream by BinaryFormatter, when the special constructor receives this `SerializationInfo` object, why it can't reconstruct the Dictionary's internal state in the specail constructor and have to do it via `IDeserializationCallback`? The special constructor have all the infomation such as key/value pairs which can be retrieve from  `SerializationInfo` object and ready to reconstruct the internal state so  what do you mean "it cannot calculate the hash codes for any of its contents until they've finished being deserialized."?

Comment: Also note that BinaryFormatter does really evil stuff, where it can allocate an object without calling its constructors, and then later go and call the deserialization constructor. Dictionary's deserialization constructor cannot guarantee that all of its values have been deserialized yet.

Comment: See also the last paragraph [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization): "*A hash table is a typical example of a class that is difficult to deserialize without using the event listener. It is easy to retrieve the key and value pairs during deserialization, but adding these objects back to the hash table can cause problems, because there is no guarantee that classes that derived from the hash table have been deserialized*"

Comment: OK let me put it in this way, if the special constructor re-calculate the hash code, what might not been deserialized and stop the special constructor doing the job? could you give me a concrete example? What I don't understand is , fro the things you think might not been deserialized, is the things that the special constructor will get from the `SerializationInfo` parameter it receives

Comment: See my latest edit -- that clearly shows the problem. Hopefully that will make sense to you. As I've said a few times, objects contained within the dictionary (keys and values) might not have been deserialized at the point that Dictionary's deserialization constructor is run