# Why formatter is BinaryFormatter that it couldn't deal with IDeserializationCallback correctly

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   var firstType = new FirstType(new SecondType(2021));
   
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(stream, firstType);

   stream.Position = 0;
   var firstTypeReturned = (FirstType)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
   Console.WriteLine(firstTypeReturned.numFromSecondType);
}

[Serializable]
class FirstType : IDeserializationCallback {
   public SecondType secondType;

   public int numFromSecondType = -1;

   public FirstType(SecondType t) {
      secondType = t;
   }

   void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender) {
      numFromSecondType = secondType.num;
   }
}

[Serializable]
class SecondType : IDeserializationCallback {
   public int num;
   public SecondType(int num) {
      this.num = num;
   }
   void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender) {
      num = 0;
   }
}
```

and the output is 2021.

I was expecting the output to be 0 because from my perpectives, `FirstType` contains a field of `SecondType` object, so in order to successfully deserialze `FirstType` instance, you must deserialize `SecondType` first, then assign the deserialzed `SecondType` intance to  `FirstType`'s field. Because `SecondType` implements `IDeserializationCallback`, so `SecondType` is not considered as "deserialization completed" until its `OnDeserialization` calls. So when `SecondType` is fully deserializated, its `num` field is 0, and then this `SecondType` instance is passed to `FirstType`, and when `FirstType` calls its `OnDeserialization`, `numFromSecondType` should be 0 (because `secondType.num` should be 0).

But it is not like this, it looks like `FirstType`'s `OnDeserialization` method is called first, followed by `SecondType`'s `OnDeserialization` method. But shouldn't it be the other way around- `SecondType`'s `OnDeserialization` method should call first, since it has to execute this method first then to be considered as fully "deserialized"

So does the formatter is so dumb that it doesn't know the correct order to call each object's `OnDeserialization` method?

Comment: Quite honestly: `BinaryFormatter` is considered obsolete, deprecated, and extremely dangerous; are you *absolutely sure* you want to use `BinaryFormatter` here? If you really really do, then it might be worth us trying to figure out the answer, but: choosing any other serializer might be a better route here.

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand `BinaryFormatter` is obsolete, but are other advanced formatter deal with `IDeserializationCallback` in the same way as `BinaryFormatter` does?

Comment: a *lot* of serializers have some kind of "after deserialization" callback, yes

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback?view=net-5.0): "*Indicates that a class is to be notified when deserialization of the entire object graph has been completed*". The object graph is considered deserialized before *any* of the callbacks are invoked. I don't think you can rely on the order that they're called: the documentation doesn't mention that at all

Comment: @MarcGravell so they all dump formatters? Shouldn't they know the correct order to callback, it looks like formatters call the callbacks in a random order?

Comment: @amjad it doesn't matter whether other formatters can do the same or more than BinaryFormatter (all of them do). `BinaryFormatter` is not just obsolete, it's dangerous and being removed from .NET altogether. If you keep using it you'll encounter more errors every year as more of its components are completely removed from .NET

Comment: @amjad instead of asking for something that works like BinaryFormatter, explain what the *real* problem is. What kind of processing do you want to perform during deserialization? And why do you care about the order? It matters. Perhaps it's a coding bug (the order *shouldn't* matter at all). Perhaps the code was trying to handle BinaryFormatter's quirks - having the *type* handle deserialization is a *bad idea*. Other formatters have better alternatives, like custom converters

Comment: @amjad object A references object B, and object B references object A; now, **you tell me**: what is the "correct" callback order? (`var b = new B(); bar a = new A { B = b }; b.A = a;`

Comment: In the example you posted there's no need for a custom deserializer/type converter in the first place. If you use eg JSON.NET, System.Text.JSON or Protocol Buffers, the entire object graph will be serialized *and* deserialized. The parent won't have to modify the child

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the clarification . This question is actually related to this question a little bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395398/why-does-dictionaryneeds-need-to-implement-ideserializationcallback   could you have a look at this question please?much appreciated

Comment: @amjad btw those types have a serious bug - instead of using the properties all serializers expect, they expose their inner implementation details: the fields. Properties aren't just syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods, they're are part of a type's interface. Fields are *not*. All serializers *and developers* expect to use properties. They also expect them to be stable, unlike fields that can change whenever the type's author wants

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos totally agree with your sentiment, but - just for the record, `BinaryFormatter` (not being reasonable) looks at fields, not properties (which means it ends up with the unspeakable field names from auto-props) - just a nit re "All serializers" (also: most other/reasonable serializers will consider *either*)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my code is just for demo purpose of course it has all kinds of bug. I just want to understand how the formatter works with IDeserializationCallback, btw, could you have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395398/why-does-dictionaryneeds-need-to-implement-ideserializationcallback/67402113#67402113

Comment: @amjad Dictionary and other built-in types use such methods because this was thought to be a good idea 21 years ago. Storing an object to a stream, similar to Python's pickle, was useful at first. It was also the only way to work with COM and legacy VB6 code which didn't have constructors with parameters. Constructing an object *had* to be done in two steps - create the instance, then fill it.

Comment: @amjad back then, it was assumed that only a single application would serialize and deserialize the data. Inter-process communication meant sending data objects between COM processes on the same machine. Even if two processes had to communicate through serialization, it was assumed a common library would be available. Things changed *completely* with XML and later JSON.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I don't get it. Could you explain a little bit more why the code in `OnDeserialization(Object sender)` method cannot be moved to `protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` so this special constructor can reconstruct the dictionary's internal state, and the dictionary doesn't need to implement IDeserializationCallback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does the formatter is so dumb that it doesn't know the correct order to call each object's `OnDeserialization` method?

It isn't a matter of dumbness; the order is *undefined* - this is because it is very easy to get loops when using `BinaryFormatter`, so all that is guaranteed is that the *various* `IDeserializationCallback` callbacks will happen *after* the regular deserialization code *for the entire graph* - the intent here being so that "parent" style objects can apply any fixups relating to "child" data. If both parent and child have  `IDeserializationCallback` callbacks, then: that sounds like a bad idea, but I guess you could track "is it done yet" in a field (honestly, I wouldn't - I'd just remove the callback from the inner object).

Comment: This question is actually related to this question a little bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395398/why-does-dictionaryneeds-need-to-implement-ideserializationcallback   could you have a look at this question please?much appreciated

Comment: The answer to that is "people thought this was a good idea 21 years ago, and they weren't wrong. At least for a couple of years"